# Python another nested lists

Tags: python, list

Take the sub list each and divide that list into another sub list by searching for particular word in the list. Here is my code:

```
for i in list_1:
      for x in i:
          regex = re.compile(r '^pft')
          matched = filter(regex.search ,x)
          print(matched)

list_1 = [['MP1 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MN1 Z A VSS VPW nft\n'],
 ['MM19 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM18 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM17 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM16 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM15 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM14 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM13 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM12 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM11 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM10 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM9 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM8 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM7 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM6 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM5 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM4 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM3 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM2 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM1 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM0 Z A VSS VPW nft\n']]
```

This the list_1 masterlist I need to grep only 1 element of the list and make the two more list from the 1st element of list if the sub list element is pft as one list and nft as one more group

example:

```
list_2 = ['MP1 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MN1 Z A VSS VPW nft\n']    
pft_list = ['MP1 Z A VDD VNW pft\n']
nft_list = ['MN1 Z A VSS VPW nft\n']
```

similarly

```
list_3 = ['MM19 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM18 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM17 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM16 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM15 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM14 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM13 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM12 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM11 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM10 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM9 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM8 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM7 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM6 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM5 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM4 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM3 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM2 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM1 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM0 Z A VSS VPW nft\n']
pft_list = ['MM19 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM18 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM17 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM16 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM15 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM14 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM13 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM12 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM11 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM10 Z A VDD VNW pft\n']
nft_list = ['MM9 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM8 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM7 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM6 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM5 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM4 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM3 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM2 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM1 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM0 Z A VSS VPW nft\n']
```

example:

```
list_2 = ['MP1 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MN1 Z A VSS VPW nft\n']
pft_list = ['MP1 Z A VDD VNW pft\n']
nft_list = ['MN1 Z A VSS VPW nft\n']
```

similarly

```
list_3 = ['MM19 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM18 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM17 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM16 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM15 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM14 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM13 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM12 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM11 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM10 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM9 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM8 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM7 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM6 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM5 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM4 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM3 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM2 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM1 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM0 Z A VSS VPW nft\n']
pft_list = ['MM19 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM18 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM17 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM16 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM15 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM14 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM13 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM12 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM11 Z A VDD VNW pft\n', 'MM10 Z A VDD VNW pft\n']
nft_list = ['MM9 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM8 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM7 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM6 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM5 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM4 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM3 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM2 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM1 Z A VSS VPW nft\n', 'MM0 Z A VSS VPW nft\n']
```

Answer (score 0):

From your examples, it seems like you just want to filter the elements that end with `pft` and `nft` respectively. You can do so with a simple list comprehension.

```
pft_list = [x for x in list_3 if x.strip().endswith("pft")]             
nft_list = [x for x in list_3 if x.strip().endswith("nft")]
```

Or just `if x.endswith("pft\n")` if the `\n` is always part of the string. This yields the same result as your expected output. Not sure about that first part with nested lists, but you could just apply this to the sublists. Note that your regex `^pft` would check whether the string *starts* with `pft`.